# 2 Apple IDs on one device

Tags: apple-id

My mom purchased an iPad about 18 months ago.  She set up an Apple ID and then connected it to her PayPal account and purchased about 18 apps and games over a few months.  Her PC crashed and had to get a new one.  She installed iTunes on her new PC but kept telling her the Apple ID was wrong.  Come to find out when she set up her Apple ID she typed in her email address wrong by leaving out 1 letter.  So she just recreated a new Apple ID with the her correct email address and went on buying apps/games.  A few months ago her iPad crashed and needed reset.  The problem is that I can't get the games she purchased originally with the 'wrong' apple ID to play.  Is it possible to play these and I'm just doing something wrong?  They are on the iPad but when you open them they ask if you want to purchase to continue, but we've already purchased them, jut on a the other apple ID.  Thoughts??

Thanks!